# Access Old Version File objects with CSOM

Tags: versioning, csom, wcf, file

I created a WCF service that uses Client-side Object Model (CSOM) to query file information from a SP Document Library.

I need to create a `List<File>` with all the files associated with all the versions for a given File stored in the Document Library. Is there a way through CSOM to get the File object of old versions of a file?

I found [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33101/spweb-getfile-for-an-old-version-of-file)! a solution for downloading an older version file, but what I need is the File object so I can access the Level property to know if the older version was also approved or not.

I'm doing the following:

```
List docList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
context.Load(docList);
context.Load(docList.RootFolder);
context.Load(docList.RootFolder.Folders);
context.ExecuteQuery();

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
ListItemCollection docCollection= listaDocs.GetItems(camlQuery);
context.Load(docCollection);
context.ExecuteQuery();

foreach(var item in docCollection)
{
     context.Load(item.File);
     var versionList = item.File.Versions;
     context.Load(versionList);
     context.ExecuteQuery();

     if(versionList != null)
     {
          foreach (FileVersion version in versionList)
          {
              // get version File object somehow
              // get version Level property somehow
          }
     }
}
```

I know that with Server-side I can access the desired info with:

```
SPFileVersionCollection versions = file.Versions;

foreach (SPFileVersion version in versions)
{
    int name = (int)version.File.Level;
}
```

But because I'm working in an external WCF, I'm using CSOM.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also load the needed properties of the objects in your 'versionlist' and of the 'File' object.

```
    var file = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName).GetItemById(id).File;
    var versions = file.Versions;
    context.Load(file, f => f.ListItemAllFields, f => f.CheckOutType, f => f.UniqueId, f => f.Title, f => f.Name);

    context.Load(versions);
    context.Load(versions, vs=>vs.Include(v=>v.CreatedBy));
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    for (int i = versions.Count; i > 0; i--)
    {
       FileVersion version = file.Versions[i - 1];   
       string label = version.VersionLabel;
       string id = version.ID.ToString();
       string filename = Path.GetFileName(version.Url);
       string ext = Path.GetExtension(version.Url);
       string tmp1 = version.IsCurrentVersion;
       string tmp2 = version.Url;
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the values of the other columns of the list item, from older versions?